# testing select option multiple times

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, storybook

How can I write a test to verify that when selecting an option multiple times in an HTML select element, the onChange function is not called?I created a mock function onChangeMock using jest.fn() to simulate the onChange and assigned to the onchange event of the selectElement. My first tests passed which is

```
    await step(
  'Selecting an option triggers the onChange function',
  async () => {
    const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
    selectElement.onchange = onChangeMock;

    userEvent.selectOptions(selectElement, 'Select1');
    expect(onChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    onChangeMock.mockClear();
    userEvent.selectOptions(selectElement, 'Select2');
    expect(onChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    onChangeMock.mockClear();
  }
);
```

but the second test when I am testing the selecting the same  option doesn't invoke the onChange failed.

```
   await step(
  'Selecting an already selected option does not trigger the onChange function',
  async () => {
    const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
    selectElement.onchange = onChangeMock;

    userEvent.selectOptions(selectElement, 'Select1');
    expect(onChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    userEvent.selectOptions(selectElement, 'Select1');
    expect(onChangeMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  }
);
```